# Кривой блок с необычной тенью

Tags: css, box-shadow

Как добиться эффекта который вы можете посмотреть ниже.
У body фон другой, а у sidebar-a другой к тому же он имеет изогнутый вид и тень.
Я пока что создал просто разметки с фоном но эффект с тенью и изгибом не смог сделать.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.page {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 1024px;
  height: 100vh;
  background: url("https://i.ibb.co/9V7gBZC/image.jpg") no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
 .page .sidebar {
  width: 262px;
  height: 100%;
  background: url("https://i.ibb.co/CzscSMX/main-page-bg.jpg");
}
 .page .content {
  width: 762px;
  height: 100%;
}
 body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  
  <div class="sidebar"></div>
  <div class="content"></div>
  
</div>
```

Также есть текущий исходник на [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e7dcavp2/4/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вот на css, но не без недостатков =)

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background: radial-gradient(circle at 250px 50%, 
    #fff,  #ddd 50%, #ddd );
}

.side {
  width:200px;
  height:100vh;
  --r: 2800px;
  background: radial-gradient(circle at calc(var(--r) + 195px) 50%, 
    #0000 var(--r),  #ddd calc(var(--r) + 2px), #ddd );
  position: relative;
}

.side:before, .side:after{
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 50%;
  top:0;
  right: 7px;
  width: 20px;
  --shadow: 5px 0 10px #aaa;
  box-shadow: var(--shadow);
  --rot: 3deg;
  transform: rotate(calc(var(--rot)));
}

.side:after {
  --rot: -3deg;
  bottom: 0;
  top: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class='side'></div>
```

Comment: Собственно, какие недостатки вы видите в своём примере? Если не считать неиспользуемую переменную в последнем `.side:after`.

Comment: @intro94 переменная как раз используемая, недостаток - адаптивность, на весь экран разверните

Comment: Хм... В последнем `.side:after` всего два свойства, и ни одного из них не использует данную переменную. Косяки - уже увидел. :)

Comment: @StrangerintheQ спасибо, попробую на основе вашего примера подогнать.

Comment: @intro94 да, но оно переопределяет такое же свойство блоком выше, попробуйте убрать - увидите результат